# Compilation issues using scalaz's MA methods on Set but not List

Tags: scala, scalaz

The following compiles just fine using scala Beta1 and scalaz snapshot 5.0:

```
val p1: Int => Boolean = (i : Int) => i > 4

val s: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
val b1 = s ∃ p1
```

And yet this does not:

```
val s: Set[Int] = Set(1, 2, 3)
val b1 = s ∃ p1
```

I get the following error:

> Found: Int => Boolean
>   Required: Boolean => Boolean

The signature of the `∃` method is:

```
def ∃(p: A => Boolean)(implicit r: FoldRight[M]): Boolean = any(p)
```

And there should be an implicit `SetFoldRight` in scope. It is exactly the same for the methods: `∀`, `∋` and `∈:` - what is going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the `A` in `MA[M[_],A]` is `Boolean` for a `Set`.  In the `Scalaz` [object](http://scalaz.googlecode.com/svn/continuous/latest/browse.sxr/scalaz/Scalaz.scala.html), there is the following implicit:

```
implicit def Function1ApplyMA[A, R](f: A => R): MA[PartialApply1Of2[Function1, A]#Apply, R] = ma[PartialApply1Of2[Function1, A]#Apply, R](f)
```

Now I don't fully understand what's going on with the types here, but it looks like the `A` in `MA[M[_],A]` is the return type of the `Function1`.  `Set[A]` extends `A => Boolean`, hence why `A` in the definition of `∃` is being inferred to `Boolean`.

One fix is to use the explicit `ma` method to convert the Set into an `MA`, rather than let implicits do the heavy lifting:

```
val s = ma(Set(1, 2, 3))
```

Comment: I see - I knew it was something to do with the fact that Set extends `A => Boolean`. The implicit you specify creates an `MA[M[_], A]` from a `Function`[I, R]`. `M[_]` is inferred as the `PartialApply1Of2` which makes the second type argument to `MA` be `R`. `R` is of course the return type of the `Function1` which is `Boolean` in this case.

Answer (score 3):

I need to add this to `object Scalaz`:

```
implicit def SetMA[M[_] <: Set[_], A](s: M[A]): MA[M, A] = ma[M, A](s)
```

But, thanks to [#2741](https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/ticket/2741), I'm running into a problem making this higher priority than the offending conversion:

```
implicit def Function1ApplyMA[A, R](f: A => R): MA[PartialApply1Of2[Function1, A]#Apply, R]  = ma[PartialApply1Of2[Function1, A]#Apply, R](f)
```

I really wish that `Seq` and `Set` were implicitly convertible to `Function1` rather than inheriting from it.

**UPDATE**

This is now [fixed](http://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/commit/26455f09ebecd723e60b8056e83d6c9db974eb75).

Comment: I think that there should also be a "cleaner" Set-based implementation for the member methods - i.e. that they do not use `FoldRight` but rather use the fact that a `Set` is a `A => Boolean`. Not that I have any idea how to do this :-)